# C# cant populate datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I had a similar problem and i was shown how to fix it, tried to post on same thread but it was limited.

i have a method private void FillLevyRoll(), i put the method in a button on click event to fill a datagridview dgvLevyRoll my problem is when i run i am not getting an error and the dgv is remaining empty.Im lost confused tried but to no avail.

The query works in SQL management studio

```
 private void FillLevyRoll()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dataTableSource = new DataTable();


            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Refrence" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '4350003' THEN amount END) AS Other" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '8400000' THEN amount END) AS Payments" +
                ", MAX(CASE WHEN AccNumber = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS Due" +
                " FROM dbo.vw_LedgerTransactions" +
                " GROUP BY Refrence ", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            conn.Open();

            adapter.Fill(dataTableSource);
            dgvLevyRoll.DataSource = dataTableSource;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application Error. err:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Debug and check wether adapter,  dataTableSource and dgvLevyRoll.DataSource hold values or not.

Comment: Remove unnecessary code to narrow down the problem. Take out where you open the connection and where you executenonquery, you only need to Fill().

Comment: ive edited the code.there is no error, i cant debug for the table is a view of  a pervasive DB which is on a server not on my machine with VisualStudio

Comment: You should be able to debug. Inserting a breakpoint at adapter.Fill(dataTableSource) and check locals for its row count. That will indicate whether you are getting results from the DB or not.